# Perl Inet Socket connect clarification

Tags: perl, sockets, client-server

I am trying to understand how Inet Socket connect works in perl. I have code snippet below.

```
socket(my $socket, Socket::PF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM, $protocol) ||
    Carp::confess "CONNECT_ERROR: Unable to create socket. $!\n";
local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { Carp::confess "Connection Timeout"; };

 eval {
            alarm(3);
            $return_val = connect( $socket, $full_address );
            alarm(0);
        };
```

Below are 3 scenarios:

1) If full address were to be defined to server and an open port, value of return_val is defined.

2) If the application were to attempt to communicate with not opened port on same server, return_val is undefined. However in this case, the alarm has not triggered.

3) However there are times when attempting to connect with server on open port, the alarm get triggered. This implies the connect statement has not yet fully executed.

I am confused with the behavior displayed in the 2nd and 3rd scenario. How does connect differentiate between not responding and slow response? I would ideally expect the server not to respond when the client is attempting to communicate at a non-opened port which implies connect should not finish execution which should trigger the alarm. Is there an internal timeout for connect? I searched for its default value but not finding any.

Am I missing something out here? Can someone please help explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all rather straightforward. An attempt to connect to the accessible server where no one is listening on the specific port quickly returns with the failure - the other side quickly informs the caller that no one is home, so to speak.

However, if you attempt to connect to the server which is not accessible or the port is open, but the listener on this port is busy with something else, connect call will *block* and wait untill the attempt to reach the server timeouts or the listener on the other side picks up the call. In this case your alarm fires, and your value is undefined - because connect did not complete in 3 seconds you have alotted.

I hope, it is clear now.